# KVM USB Passthrough and Zydas usb wireless adapter: device or resource busy

Tags: usb, debian, linux-kvm, wifi-driver

i'm tring to setup a kernel testing virtualmachine for a 80211 module.

i start my machine with this command:

```
kvm -m 512 -net nic -net vde -usb -usbdevice host:0ace:1215  ktesting.img
```

i set up a kvm image with debian connected to a vde_switch at the eth0 interface and with a

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0ace:1215 ZyDAS ZD1211B 802.11g
```

i installed the 'zd1211-firmware' and give the right permissions in /dev/bus/usb.

the wlan0 interface go up:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56  
          inet addr:192.168.2.15  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1706 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1458 (1.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:72:71:dc:a3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

but when i try to use wpa_supplicant to connect to my router:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c conf
```

i got this output(stderr and stout):

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed 
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING - signal 2 received
```

i tried using the wifi adapter on my laptop to connect to the same network with the same config file installing only the zd1211-firmware and it work perfectly.
it's not a problem of my compiled kernel as the problem persist with the stock debian kernel (wheezy)

i tried to post this on serverfault, as i'm not sure whatever it's the right one and i've got no answers i'll post it there too

host lsmod:

```
$ lsmod                                                                 
Module                  Size  Used by
iwlwifi               163978  0 
mac80211              317352  1 iwlwifi
tun                    18406  0 
nls_utf8               12457  0 
isofs                  35128  0 
usb_storage            43974  0 
uvcvideo               62300  0 
bbswitch               12867  0 
binfmt_misc            12958  1 
uinput                 17538  1 
loop                   22961  0 
fuse                   62620  1 
kvm_intel             118110  0 
kvm                   294774  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    55079  1 
snd_hda_intel          26341  3 
snd_hda_codec          83277  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 17319  0 
arc4                   12459  2 
snd_hwdep              13190  1 snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_vmalloc      12665  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       12563  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         25974  1 uvcvideo
i915                  366725  2 
videodev               79475  1 uvcvideo
cfg80211              138905  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
drm_kms_helper         31378  1 i915
snd_pcm                64207  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         12970  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
media                  18185  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_seq                45226  0 
drm                   184723  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
thinkpad_acpi          61290  0 
coretemp               12855  0 
iTCO_wdt               17092  0 
ac                     12625  0 
evdev                  17613  23 
acpi_cpufreq           12973  1 
snd_seq_device         13177  1 snd_seq
pcspkr                 12633  0 
snd_timer              22813  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
nvram                  13093  1 thinkpad_acpi
rfkill                 19063  3 cfg80211,thinkpad_acpi
iTCO_vendor_support    12705  1 iTCO_wdt
mperf                  12454  1 acpi_cpufreq
i2c_algo_bit           12842  1 i915
battery                13147  0 
i2c_i801               16973  0 
power_supply           13520  2 ac,battery
i2c_core               23960  6 drm,i915,i2c_i801,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,videodev
psmouse                64970  0 
serio_raw              12976  0 
snd                    53078  15               snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkp ad_acpi,snd_seq_device
wmi                    13244  0 
tpm_tis                17316  0 
tpm                    17938  1 tpm_tis
tpm_bios               12949  1 tpm
microcode              25946  0 
soundcore              13027  1 snd
processor              28456  9 acpi_cpufreq
video                  17686  1 i915
button                 12938  1 i915
ext4                  352574  3 
crc16                  12344  1 ext4
jbd2                   67479  1 ext4
mbcache                13115  1 ext4
xts                    12723  24 
gf128mul               13048  1 xts
dm_crypt               22675  3 
dm_mod                 63760  16 dm_crypt
sg                     25992  0 
sr_mod                 21946  0 
sd_mod                 36206  3 
cdrom                  35213  1 sr_mod
crc_t10dif             12349  1 sd_mod
crc32c_intel           12748  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13022  0 
aesni_intel            50436  97 
aes_x86_64             16844  1 aesni_intel
aes_generic            33027  2 aesni_intel,aes_x86_64
cryptd                 14561  26 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
ahci                   25050  2 
libahci                22868  1 ahci
libata                141446  2 ahci,libahci
scsi_mod              162624  5 sg,usb_storage,libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
sdhci_pci              17846  0 
firewire_ohci          31838  0 
sdhci                  27126  1 sdhci_pci
ehci_hcd               40285  0 
firewire_core          48934  1 firewire_ohci
mmc_core               68804  2 sdhci,sdhci_pci
crc_itu_t              12348  1 firewire_core
xhci_hcd               73866  0 
e1000e                129819  0 
thermal                17384  0 
usbcore               129093  5 uvcvideo,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,xhci_hcd
usb_common             12355  1 usbcore
thermal_sys            18093  3 video,thermal,processor
```

Comment: added lsmod because it could be some module failure